# Trying to Print multiple 2D arrays on the same line row by row

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have 10 2-D String arrays that look like the readout of a digital clock when printed out. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to print the consecutive arrays out next to each other row-by-row. I have all the arrays I need representing the correct numbers, but the actual printing is not going well...

prompt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBcO2.jpg

```
public static void digital(String [][] first, String[][] second, String[][] colon, String[][] third, String[][] fourth)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
         for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
         {
            System.out.print(first[j][i]);
            System.out.print(second[j][i]);
            System.out.print(colon[j][i]);
            System.out.print(third[j][i]);
            System.out.print(fourth[j][i]);  
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   } //method to print the clock out
```

expected: proper digital clock readout

actual:
this jumbled mess

```
  | ||  | |        || ||||
 - --  -        ----  -       
 - --       |   - --       |
```

Comment: Nice approach but you're printing the elements of each array in each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops are all over the place. `j` should be vertical and `i` horizontal so lets start from there.

The outer loop represents the rows of the clock. In this you want to print every element in `first[j]` then every element in `second[j]` and so on. Note that the printing happens in the first row of your output. Don't forget to add spaces in between. After the first line is finished start a new line and repeat until every row is printed.

There are ways to do this in less lines, but it's easier to see how to handle printing on the command prompt this way.

```
public static void digital(String [][] first, String[][] second, String[][] colon, String[][] third, String[][] fourth) {

    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

        for(in i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(first[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");

        for(in i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(second[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");

        for(in i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(colon[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");

        for(in i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(third[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");

        for(in i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(fourth[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

} //method to print the clock out
```

Comment: You guys are life savers!!
That last bit in particular was exactly what I was looking for, F.G.! All I needed to do was set the i < 3 to i <= 3 and the j <6 to j <= 6 with your improved loops and now it works precisely the way it's supposed to! This project was due tonight at midnight and now I can rest easy. 2-D arrays have always been a little bit of a stumbling block for me. And yeah, I forgot that the outer loop is for rows...Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend rewriting digital as a more universal method. Pass array of digits or ArrayList of digits. It will also simplify your life in the future!

```
public static void digital(ArrayList<String[][]> arrays) {
    // we don't have anything to print
    if (arrays.size() == 0)
        return;

    // for each column
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.get(0).length; i++) {

        // for each digit
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays.size(); j++) {
            String[][] arr = arrays.get(j);

            // print current row of a current digit
            for (int k = 0; k < arr[0].length; k++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][k]);
            }
            // if you need spacing between digits, you can add one more
            // System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is an example of how you can run this function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String[][]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new String[][]{
            {" ", "-", " "},
            {"-", " ", "-"},
            {"-", " ", "-"},
            {"-", " ", "-"},
            {" ", "-", " "},
    });

    list.add(new String[][]{
            {" ", " ", " "},
            {" ", "-", " "},
            {" ", " ", " "},
            {" ", "-", " "},
            {" ", " ", " "},
    });

    list.add(new String[][]{
            {" ", "-", " "},
            {"-", " ", "-"},
            {"-", " ", "-"},
            {"-", " ", "-"},
            {" ", "-", " "},
    });

    digital(list);
}
```

This function scales to any dimension of digits, just be sure that column count of all digits matches.